# HTML Input field, remember the cursor location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

I have an application with an Input field which needs to be converted to Uppercase as soon as the User enters a character. This is working as expected.

But if the user tries to enter a character between an already existing word, the cursor is pushed to the end of the Input field. Is there a way I can keep the cursor in the proper location?

Before you down vote, I did check out posts in Stack Overflow and other places. Couldn't find a proper solution. Do provide your feedback.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/3s47tyq3/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#referenceNo").on('keyup change', function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="referenceNo">Reference No</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="referenceNo" name="referenceNo" value="HELLO WORLD!" />
```

Try to input a character between "Hello World!", the cursor will be pushed to the end of the word. This needs fixing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Achieve visualization by CSS and for value sending to server you can use javascript.

Like: 
this is CSS Code

```
#abc {
    text-transform: uppercase
}
```

this is HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="abc" />
```

this is javascript:

```
$("#abc").on("change", function(){ var x = $("#abc").val().toUpperCase(); });
```

you can use "keyup" event for instant value if you have not required then you don't have need to bind extra event with your code.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate the simpler solution.

Comment: Yup, just did. Was away for the weekend, so the delay.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You can use `setSelectionRange` Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s47tyq3/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#referenceNo").on('keyup change', function (e) {            
        var startPos = this.selectionStart,
        endPos = this.selectionEnd;    

        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());    
        // restore cursor
        this.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos );

    });
});
```

Also you can use pure CSS

```
   #referenceNo {
     text-transform: uppercase
   }
```

Comment: The css solution is nice! Where did you found it?

Comment: Tried this, it works. Will be using this code for now. Thanks. Will keep the question open for a day or so to see if a better answer turns up.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do this by CSS. Add [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) property to the element:

```
#referenceNo {
    text-transform: uppercase
}
```

No script needed.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s47tyq3/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: In the JS code, I still am getting small characters. This is a neat trick, did see it in one of the other question but not useful in my case. Thanks for the suggestion.